# Android Json parsing with complicated arrays

Tags: android

```
[
  {
    "countries": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "country": "India"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "country": "Australia"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "country": "Srilanka"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "country": "Pakistan"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "country": "Switzerland"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How to parse this Json Response in Android. i am not getting any proper solution.
please help me.

Comment: See [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) tutorial. It helps you.

Comment: You need to have any name for the array.You have not mentioned it.

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this...

```
JSONArray arr = locs.getJSONArray("countries");


for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject rec = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = rec.getInt("id");
    String con = rec.getString("country");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   JSONArray jArr=new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i=0;i<jArr.length;i++)
    {
    id[]=jArr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");
    con[]=jArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("country");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html

I've also seen [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation) used in Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONArray countriesobj = new JSONArray();   
 JSONObject json;
            try {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                json = jObject;

                countriesobj = json.getJSONArray("countries");

                country = new String[countriesobj.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < countriesobj.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject e = countriesobj.getJSONObject(i);

                    country[i] = e.getString("country");

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```